Is it possible to turn off "help me write" in Chrome via html attributes or javascript?
Chrome is slowly rolling out a feature where when a user clicks into an editable field it pops up a prompt to "Help me write" with an AI.  This feature can be individually disabled by a user in Chrome Settings > Experimental AI > Help me write (when present, not all users have it yet).  Is there something similar to autocomplete="off" that might disable that?  In a more complicated web app, having that pop up is distracting for a user.


The feature seems to be behind a feature flag, because some people have Settings > Experimental AI > Help me write and some do not. I do not have it, but some coworkers do.

I think this is a user preference, not something the site can control.

I find it a harsh and poor decision to close this question because it would not be about programming. The TS clearly asks if there is a programming way to disable the feature in question. The fact that there is none does not make it a question that is not about programming.

@FrankConijn-SupportUkraine whiel I agree that the close reason is wrong, there is no reason to reopen it just to instantly reclsoe it as duplicate that has been linked above. not about programming doe snot mean that it is not related to programming in global sense but not within the scope of SO.

@tachoshy What duplicate are you talking about? Maybe I missed it somewhere?
